# Dynamic fields JS value showing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, var

**Below is simple HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="user[0].first_name" name="user[0].first_name" placeholder="First Name">
```

**And here's the JS:**

```
    emailIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= emailIndex; i++) {
       data["user[" + i + "].first_name"] = $("#user[" + i + "].first_name").val();

    }
```

If I try to print the ID *user[0].first_name* returns: **undefined**

What's wrong there?

Thanks!

Comment: So you take the value of the input field and assign it to data. Whats in ```data["user[0].first_name"]``` ?

Comment: Solved. You can't pass dot's in the ID field. I used: **user1first_name**

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works !

```
for (var i = 0; i <= emailIndex; i++) {
       alert($('#user_'+i.toString()+'_first_name').val());
    }
```

We need to change integer to string first.
Also dont forgot to take out dot operator from the id (see Nagesh's answer)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

in above code, `#user[" + i + "].first_name` after execute it will be `#user[0].first_name`

here, the `jquery` wont check like where `id = user[0].first_name`

but it will consider it as a `id = user[0]` and `class = first_name`

so, you wont get correct results in jquery but you can do it with javascript

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jvbgksy6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, You can't give id="user[0].first_name".

Instead, try to create 'input' elements using jQuery based on number of users like

```
$.each(users, function(index, user){

   $(body).append('<input id="'+user.first_name+'"></input>');

});
```

OR

```
$(body).append('<input id="'+user[0].first_name+'"></input>');
```

Now

You can get val() of it by JS code You wrote